# A Linux based VPN server that is compatible with the built in VPN client in Windows

Tags: windows, linux, vpn

OpenVPN looks good, but I'm hoping for a VPN server that is compatible with the built in VPN client in Windows.

When doing a quick search it just comes up with VPN clients compatible with Windows.

Ideally it would also support active directory authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look at [StrongSwan](http://www.strongswan.org/). According to [their wiki](http://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Windows7) it should be compatible with Windows 7:

> Windows 7 fully supports the IKEv2 (RFC 4306) and MOBIKE (RFC 4555)
>   standards through Microsoft's Agile VPN functionality and is therefore
>   able to interoperate with a strongSwan VPN gateway using these
>   protocols. strongSwan currently can authenticate Windows 7 clients
>   either on the basis of X.509 Machine Certificates using RSA signatures
>   (case A) or Username/Password using EAP-MSCHAP v2 (case B).